# Comparision method violates its general contract exception

Tags: java, collections, comparator

I have check why this exception occurs. Could you please guide me? What I am doing wrong in below code block?

```
        Collections.sort(discountGroupDetailList, new Comparator<DiscountGroupDetail>() {
            long bdsIdOne;
            long bdsIdTwo;

            public int compare(DiscountGroupDetail discountGroupDetailOne, DiscountGroupDetail discountGroupDetailTwo) {
                boolean discOne;
                boolean discTwo;
                SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMATER = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
                int compVal = 0;
                discOne = discountGroupDetailOne != null && discountGroupDetailOne.getServiceId() != null
                        && discountGroupDetailOne.getServiceId().getCodeAndVersion() != null
                        && discountGroupDetailOne.getServiceId().getCodeAndVersion().getCodeDetail() != null
                        && discountGroupDetailOne.getServiceId().getCodeAndVersion().getCodeDetail().getCode() != null;

                discTwo = discountGroupDetailTwo != null && discountGroupDetailTwo.getServiceId() != null
                        && discountGroupDetailTwo.getServiceId().getCodeAndVersion() != null
                        && discountGroupDetailTwo.getServiceId().getCodeAndVersion().getCodeDetail() != null
                        && discountGroupDetailTwo.getServiceId().getCodeAndVersion().getCodeDetail().getCode() != null;

                if (discOne == true && discTwo == true) {
                    bdsIdOne = MessageBuilderHelper.getBaseDiscountServiceById(discountGroupDetailOne.getServiceId())
                            .getBdsIdNbr();

                    bdsIdTwo = MessageBuilderHelper.getBaseDiscountServiceById(discountGroupDetailTwo.getServiceId())
                            .getBdsIdNbr();
                    compVal = (int) (bdsIdOne - bdsIdTwo);
                }



                DateRange dateRangeOne = discountGroupDetailOne != null ? discountGroupDetailOne.getDateSegment() : null;
                DateRange dateRangeTwo = discountGroupDetailTwo != null ? discountGroupDetailTwo.getDateSegment() : null;

                if (compVal == 0 && dateRangeOne != null && dateRangeTwo != null) {

                    Date date = new Date();
                    compVal = DATE_FORMATER.format(date.parse(dateRangeOne.getStartDate())).compareTo(
                            DATE_FORMATER.format(date.parse(dateRangeTwo.getStartDate())));
                }

                DiscountCode discountTypeOne = (discountGroupDetailOne != null && discountGroupDetailOne
                        .getVolumeDiscountGroupDetail() != null) ? DiscountCode.getDiscount(discountGroupDetailOne
                        .getVolumeDiscountGroupDetail().getType()) : null;
                DiscountCode discountTypeTwo = (discountGroupDetailTwo != null && discountGroupDetailTwo
                        .getVolumeDiscountGroupDetail() != null) ? DiscountCode.getDiscount(discountGroupDetailTwo
                        .getVolumeDiscountGroupDetail().getType()) : null;

                boolean isFXG = ("FXG".equals(discountGroupDetailOne.getServiceGeography()) || (discountGroupDetailOne
                        .getServiceId() != null && "FXG".equals(discountGroupDetailOne.getServiceId().getOperatingCompany())))
                        && ("FXG".equals(discountGroupDetailTwo.getServiceGeography()) || (discountGroupDetailTwo
                                .getServiceId() != null && "FXG".equals(discountGroupDetailTwo.getServiceId()
                                .getOperatingCompany())));

                if (compVal == 0 && discountTypeOne != null && discountTypeTwo != null && isFXG) {
                    compVal = ((int) (Integer.parseInt(discountTypeOne.getDiscountID()) - Integer.parseInt(discountTypeTwo
                            .getDiscountID())));
                }

                return compVal;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: please give us the exact error message, including stack trace if possible, and in what line the exception occurs.

Comment: I can see right now that if A has a null discount type, and B has a non-null discount type, and C has a different non-null discount type, and everything else is equal, then A == B and A == C and B != C according to your comparator.

Comment: @Daniel.Schroeder. Yes

Answer (score 3):

@immibis spotted the answer before I could.  To generalize the principle: Say you're writing a comparator that compares multiple pairs of keys.  You want to compare the first pair, and then if that doesn't give you a < or > answer, compare the second pair, and if you still don't have < or >, compare the third pair, and so on.

The rule here is that after comparing the first pair, you may not go on to the second pair unless the keys in the first pair are *equal*.  In your case, they're equal if both have a "code" and the codes are equal, *or if they're **both** null*.  Your mistake is that you go on to the next pair if only one code is null.  They're not equal in that case.  I guess your thinking is that you can't compare the codes if one item doesn't have a code.  *But you must*.  You need to decree that an item with no code is less than an item with a code (or greater than; it depends on how you want to see them in your sorted array); and you have to check for that, and return (for instance) a negative number if the left item has a null code, and a positive number if the right item has a null code.

Then you need to do the same with the date range; if one argument has a date range and the other doesn't, they are not equal and you must return a negative or positive number, instead of proceeding to the third key.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost always caused by your comparator either not being transitive or not being asymmetric. For transitivity, given three `DiscountGroupDetail` objects `a`, `b`, and `c`, if `a` precedes `b` and `b` precedes `c`, then the general contract requires that `a` precede `c` in all cases. Likewise, if `a` equals `b` and `b` equals `c`, then it is required that `a` equals `c`. For asymmetry, swapping the comparison order for two objects `a` and `b` that do not return `0` must return a number of the opposite sign.

Given your complex logic, it's difficult for me to determine exactly where things are going wrong, but the above is what you need to check.

Comment: actually I have list of 77 object in list. Exception fires when it enters in last if block and returning comVal as 1. case those two object have different discountID.

Comment: @shreyanshjogi - I think @immibis identified one problem with your comparison logic. There may be other problems as well. When the entire logic changes depending on certain fields being `null`, it's easy to get into trouble. For instance, given `a`, `b`, and `c`, if only `b` has certain fields `null`, then comparing `a` and `b` or comparing `b` and `c` will not be consistent with comparing `a` and `c`.

Comment: Sure I will try to modify whole logic and keeping in mind that comparison between object should have values to compare